# PHP / CodeIgniter - deleting a record based on multiple WHERE conditions via array of data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using PHP/Code Igniter for my project and I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this query.

I have an array of data that I want to use as my `WHERE` clause for deleting a record.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CustomerID] => 8
            [Denomination] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CustomerID] => 9
            [Denomination] => 425
        )

)
```

I am trying to do something like so:

```
public function remove_customers_from_order($formData){
        $this->db
        ->where($formData)
        ->delete("customer_rewards");
    }
```

Is there a more effective way than to do a loop and delete each time? `CustomerID` and `Denomination` both match the column names for my WHERE clause.

**Desired Result:**

`DELETE FROM customer_rewards WHERE CustomerID = 8 AND Denomination = 40;
 DELETE FROM customer_rewards WHERE CustomerID = 9 AND Denomination = 425;`

**Error:**

When running it like this, I am getting the following error: `Array to string conversion database/DB_query_builder.php`

Comment: Yes. Executing a query inside a loop is never efficient

Comment: @Strawberry - Thats what I am trying to figure out here. I have not taken the loop approach, trying to pass an array but having some trouble.

Comment: As per the `CodeIgniter`  docs, there is no way to delete multiple records at a time as like inserting multiple records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I think you can use:
foreach($formData as $w){
    $this->db->or_where("(`CustomerID` = '".$w['CustomerID']."' AND `Denomination`='".$w['Denomination'].')",NULL,false);
}
$this->db->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is more efficient:

```
DELETE 
  FROM customer_rewards 
 WHERE (CustomerID = 8 AND Denomination = 40)
    OR (CustomerID = 8 AND Denomination = 425);
```

Can you figure out how to adapt your loop accordingly?

Comment: My problem is that the customerID + denomination could be anything. So the combination of customer ID and the denomination needs to be found and removed. Both of them being 8 just happened to be my example.

Comment: It was a poor example. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Although it already has an accepted answer - the correct way in CI of doing this would be:

```
$arrData = [
    [
        'CustomerID' => 8,
        'Denomination' => 40
    ],
    [
        'CustomerID' => 9,
        'Denomination' => 425
    ]
];

foreach($arrData AS $arrItem)
{
    $this->db->or_group_start();
        $this->db->where('CustomerID', $arrItem['CustomerID']);
        $this->db->where('Denomination', $arrItem['Denomination']);
    $this->db->group_end();
}
$this->db->delete('customer_rewards');
```

> in this case you are protected from SQL Injections

Comment: This is awesome, glad to know you can do such as thing!